# Syntax for selecting html element in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

Is there any angularJS way to write following function.

**EDIT**: I wanted to know what is equivalent to $ in angularJS

```js
//Horizontally scroll studenton button click
        function slideStudentLeft() {
            $('#divStudent').scrollLeft($('#divStudent').scrollLeft() - $('#divStudent div').first().width());
        }

        function slideStudentRight() {
            $('#divStudent').scrollLeft($('#divStudent').scrollLeft() + $('#divStudent div').first().width());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It was pretty simple i just needed to replace the $ with angular.element.

```js
//Horizontally scroll studenton button click
        function slideStudentLeft() {
            angular.element('#divStudent').scrollLeft(angular.element('#divStudent').scrollLeft() - angular.element('#divStudent div').first().width());
        }

        function slideStudentRight() {
            angular.element('#divStudent').scrollLeft(angular.element('#divStudent').scrollLeft() + angular.element('#divStudent div').first().width());
        }
```

Comment: might want to take a look at this (caching) :http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/efficientjs.shtml